# Is it possible to fix size of stack in declaration?

Tags: c++

While using `std::stack`, can I fix size of stack in similar way to declaring size of array?
e.g

```
size1=5;
char array[size1];
```

Comment: Yes, indirectly. But why?

Comment: I want to add two numbers (circa 5000 and 6000 chars) read from file, and i wanted to do it with stacks made from tables, but i thought that it _might_ be easier with std::stack.

Comment: That doesn’t explain why you want to limit the stack size. In fact, you probably *don’t* want to do that.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the container in another type that restricts its maximum size, yes.

I'm not clear on why you'd want to, though.